# Css selector, elements between two classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to write a css selector that can select the elements between two clases .

Example:

```
<div class='start'></div>
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div class='end'></div>
```

My question is following: is there a way to use css selector to select two divs between the `.start` div and `.end` div?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option is to use `:not()` selector in CSS. CSS does not have a mechanism where you can select elements in between.

```css
div:not(.start):not(.end) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='start'>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div class='end'>D</div>
```

Comment: An alternative could be `.start ~ div:not(.end)`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.start ~ div:not(.end) {

    border: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='start'>start</div>
 <div></div> 
 <div></div>
 <div class='end'>end</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Addtion to @Nidhin Josephr's answer you can also do it without adding `.start` & `.end` class using `:not()` with `:nth-child` `:nth-last-child` pseudo selector.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sumitpatel/pen/RXxJbg)

**HTML**

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-last-child(1)){
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div:not(.start):not(.end) {
  color: blue;
}
```

For reference go through this link below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not